# CentOS7にWi-Fiアダプタのドライバをインストールしたい

Tags: centos, kernel

CentOS7にWi-FIアダプタ「AC1750 EDimax 3T3R」のドライバをインストールしたいのですが、makeで以下のエラーが出ます。

```
[root@test EW7833UAC_linux_v4.3.21_17997.20160531]# make
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/3.10.0-1062.4.3.el7.x86_64/build M=/usr/local/EW7833UAC_linux_4.3.21_kernel_2.6-3.15/EW7833UAC_linux_v4.3.21_17997.20160531  modules
make: *** /lib/modules/3.10.0-1062.4.3.el7.x86_64/build: そのようなファイルやディレクトリはありません.  中止.
make: *** [modules] エラー 2
```

エラーにあるファイルを調べてみたところ、指定のファイルは既にあるようです。

```
[root@test 3.10.0-1062.4.3.el7.x86_64]# dirs
/lib/modules/3.10.0-1062.4.3.el7.x86_64
[root@test 3.10.0-1062.4.3.el7.x86_64]# ls
build              modules.builtin      modules.modesetting  source
extra              modules.builtin.bin  modules.networking   updates
kernel             modules.dep          modules.order        vdso
modules.alias      modules.dep.bin      modules.softdep      weak-updates
modules.alias.bin  modules.devname      modules.symbols
modules.block      modules.drm          modules.symbols.bin
[root@test 3.10.0-1062.4.3.el7.x86_64]#
```

インストール手順は以下のサイトのダウンロード欄のZipファイルの中に入っているPDFファイルを参考に実行しました。

https://www.edimax.com/edimax/download/download/data/edimax/global/download/for_home/wireless_adapters/wireless_adapters_ac1750_dual-band/ew-7833uac

ご教授お願いします。

Comment: ダウンロードしたファイル名も明記した方が良いのかなと思います。あなたがダウンロードしたのは恐らく バージョンが"4.3.21" のようで、PDFが含まれるのもこちらですが、"1.0.1.0" の方が日付的に新しそうです。 / また、PDFのファイル名を見る限り Ubuntu 向けなのは注意が必要です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**/lib/modules/3.10.0-1062.4.3.el7.x86_64/build** はシンボリックリンクになっていて、リンク先は **kernel-devel-3.10.0-1062.4.3.el7.x86_64** パッケージに含まれます。
`yum install kernel-devel-3.10.0-1062.4.3.el7.x86_64` とバージョン指定でインストールするといいと思います。